# Flash sdk on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, plugins, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn actionScript 3.0 from scratch and I was advised to use Intellij IDEA for development.However I am really struggling to install Flash SDK in it. Could someone help me with it? Please don't refer me to documentation, I tried already and faild miserably. Thanx

Comment: What difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: Erm, just generally got confused, I downloaded flex sdk and not too sure what to do with it now =/

Comment: What version of Idea do you use? 11?

Answer (score 6):

**It is only for Ultimate Edition**

The basic setup of IDEA for as3 project is:

1. Install & unpack (if needed) Flex SDK
2. With Idea opened, choose `File`->`Project Structure` (even if project isn't opened or created)
3. In `SDK` section, press `+` at the top of second columnd and choose `Flex SDK` from dropdown list
4. Select folder, where you have previously unpacked Flex SDK (where you have subfolders `bin`, `frameworkds` and so on)
5. Return to `Project` section in `Project Structure` window.
6. Choose default Project SDK from dropdown list (near `New...` button)
7. Press OK.

Now, you are prepared for project creating (via `File`->`New Project...`)

Comment: There we go, read that, there starts my problem.ok, choose Flex SDK from dropdown menu... There is no Flash SDK on dropdown menu...

Comment: I've missed your last answer. AS3 support is only Ultimate Edition feature

Comment: Oooohhhh, there goes the problem =( oh well, thanx a lot anyways =)

Comment: Here is the Editions Comparison: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Yes, but you can use it for free 30 days trial (I don't work in JetBrains :-D ).

Comment: If this is all how I can help you - good luck with new job :) and please, set question answered.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the 3.6 SDK download has really messed up permissions. IntelliJ would let me select the folder, but just quietly do nothing.

I had to `sudo chmod -R a+r [sdk dir]` and `sudo chmod -R a+x [sdk dir]/frameworks` to get it to actually add the SDK after selecting.

Do the first one and see if it works, I was being pretty callous with my chmod'ing, but the `frameworks` directory had **no** permissions at all. It, at least, needs to be `+rx`.